# Unable to convert color image to grayscale in android opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

This is the part of code which is not working good. I know this question has been asked earlier, but i have done everything i could do but still couldn't figure out the reason. This is the portion of code

```
    Mat imgSource = original_image.clone();

    // apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Log.i(TAG, "Blur");
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    // convert the image to black and white
    Log.i(TAG, "B&W");
    Log.i(TAG,Integer.toString(imgSource.type()));
    Log.i(TAG,Integer.toString(imgSource.channels()));

    Mat gray = new Mat(imgSource.size(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
    Log.i(TAG, "Canny");
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 50, 50);

    // find the contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Log.i(TAG, "Contours");
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,
            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Log.i(TAG,"Contours done");

    //if no contours are detected
    if(contours.size() == 0){
        Log.i(TAG,"contour size is 0");
        return gray;
    }
```

In my Logcat i see the message "contour size is 0".

When i load the gray mat, i see a coloured image which explains why their were no contours detected.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you may remove this row from your code:

```
Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 50, 50);
```

Comment: No even after removing canny, contour size is 0 and loading gray mat shows a coloured image.

Comment: I guess the issue is with Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); . As loading gray mat after this line shows a coloured image rather than grey image.